# what does UNCONFIGURED BAD mean

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, sas, megaraid

have a few SAS ssd's, the $4000 kind {manufacturer name withheld}.
I have had two now go to `unconfigured bad` after 1-2 hours of only *powered on* use, such that I am skeptical that the drive is not really bad but more likely a software or firmware bug somewhere.

This is on an Avago Megaraid SAS 9361, where the drive light will blink on boot up, the system will take an extra couple minutes before getting to the Megaraid bios screen, and then `make unconfigured good` for the SSD is grayed out, as well as the size of the disk showing 0kb where my others show 3.84TB. I have never had a problem like this with other SAS (spinning) disks.

What does `unconfigured bad` really mean?  And is there a solution for  going from *bad* to *good* in this case?  Does it mean I need to warranty replace the drive?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I had a 8TB spinning disk which the operator, by mistake, started a disk format on through the MegaRAID boot menu. Then interrupted the format. The drive then showed 0k size, UBAD. So seems like the drive isn't formatted properly. Being an SSD, looks like you may have run into a firmware issue (or really unlucky bad manufacturing). I was able to recover my drive after a reboot, I was able to get the format done and the drive shows normal again.